# App running in container cannot connect to couchbase on VM localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Ive a simple webapp running on docker container which makes DB connection to couchbase.

My couchbase is currently running on a VM localhost. (not another container).

I tried issue a command

```
docker run --net=host -p 8081:8081 {**image-name-one**}  // This connects without issue
```

Now, I need another instance of the same app but different port and for that I created a bridge network with ip - 192.168.0.1 then modified connection string to use network ip

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 192.168.0.0/24 --gateway 192.168.0.1 test
```

Now, I tried running 2nd container with below ports

```
docker run --net=test -p 8083:8081 {**2nd-image-name**}  // This will never connect to the database
```

Any insight would be greatly helpful.

Comment: What software is running your VM (not sure if it matters, but it might)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im using Ubuntu 16.04.

I found a work around by adding the subnet to my firewall to allow connections to any ports.

Now, I can get my services connect to Couchbase.